# how to know another branch top commit without checkout branch

Tags: git

As there are many branches in my local repo, while I do not fully use the git stash related operation,
I prefer to use different branch to handle my different period task,
While there is a question now, with times goes by, I can not remember clearly the top commit each branch,
but checkout different branch one by one is a little cost to me, is there a method to query every branch top commit without checkout branch? Or is there ongoing feature?

Thanks
Charley

Comment: `git log branch-name`

Answer (score 2):

Use [git for-each-ref](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref).

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format="%(refname:lstrip=2) %(objectname) %(subject)"
```

`git for-each-ref` iterates all refs and prints their information.

`refs/heads` limits the refs to the local branches, which are `refs/heads/*`. If you also want to see the remote tracking branches, like `origin/master`, you can add `refs/remotes`.

`--format` defines the output. `%(refname)` is the placeholder for the ref name. `:lstrip=2` strips the first 2 parts of the full ref name, like `ref/heads/` and `refs/remotes/`. `%(objectname)` is the SHA-1 of the commit. `%(subject)` is the subject of the commit message. It's the first non-blank line of the message.

Comment: add my great thanks to your comments, i think it should be work is the git version upper than 2.5.6 after check the link you pasted, while a pity thing to me is my company working env git version is only 1.8.3.1, do you have any idea/WA to achieve that goal?

Comment: @CharleyCui I searched the doc of v1.8.3.1. The cause might be `:lstrip=2`. Remove `:lstrip=2` and have a try.

Comment: @CharleyCui You could also try `%(refname:short)`.